# The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound #2

Tags: c#, .net

I know this is a duplicate to some questions here, but believe me I've tried all of them, and no luck.

I am new to C#+MySQL.

I have a database with 2 tables, programmers and softwares. I have a column in the softwares table named programmersid. It's one to many relation. I have two listboxes. The first one is with the programmers name, and when I click on a programmer, it's showing me the softwares that he has made.

When I click on a software, the text will be put into a textbox, and I have an update button. When I click it, it should update the name of that software.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataSet ds;
    private SqlConnection conn;
    private SqlDataAdapter programmersadapter;
    private SqlDataAdapter softwaresadapter;


    protected string connectionString = "Data Source=ICEBOX19-PC\\ICEBOX;Initial Catalog=software;Integrated Security=True";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand programmersselect = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name FROM programmers", conn);
        programmersadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(programmersselect);

        SqlCommand softwaresselect = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM softwares WHERE programmerid = @ID", conn);
        softwaresselect.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int));
        softwaresadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(softwaresselect);
        showme();
    }
    private void showme()
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        conn.Open();
        programmersadapter.Fill(ds, "programmers");
        conn.Close();
        listBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["programmers"];
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update softwares set name='" + textBox1.Text + "' where programmerid=" + listBox2.SelectedValue.ToString(), conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        reload();
    }
    private void reload()
    {
        //listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged -= listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
        softwaresadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = listBox1.SelectedValue;
        var table = new DataTable();
        softwaresadapter.Fill(table);
        conn.Close();
        listBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
        listBox2.ValueMember = "id";
        listBox2.DataSource = table;
        //listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reload();
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox2.Text;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "");
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

> The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound.

It comes from the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` in the `button1.Click`.

I've tried to change the :

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update softwares set name='" + textBox1.Text + "' where programmerid=" + listBox2.SelectedValue, conn);
```

to

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update softwares set name='" + textBox1.Text + "' where programmerid=" + listBox2.SelectedValue.ToString(), conn);
```

But I also get the same thing. Do you guys have some ideas ? I am looking for this since 2 hours now.

**PS: I get the same error even if I try to delete**

```
        private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("delete from softwares where id="+listBox2.SelectedItem, conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You have not set the `Value` of the parameter `@ID`, have you?

Comment: listBox2.ValueMember = "id"; I guess I've set it

Comment: Not sure that this could be the answer but it seems that your listbox2.Item is wrongly interpted as a DataRowView. Try to change the `var table = new DataTable` to `DataTable table = new DataTable()`

Comment: @Steve thanks but ... I get the same error.

Comment: @rs you can't set it like listBox2.SelectedItem.Value, you get error from compilation

Answer (score -1):

```cs
private void PopulateListBox(DataTable dt)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ls.Items.Add(row["id"]);
                }
            }
```

Then, calls

```
   string value = ls.Items[0].ToString();
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: @csharpvid sorry for my previous posts. I modify some things in your code.
First, create a method to populate your listbox, from the datatable. 

    private void PopulateListBox(DataTable dt)  
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                ls.Items.Add(row["id"]);
            }
        }

Then, access the item, using ls.Items[0]

Hope this helps!